Trying to merge groupby results to get a report in single query
I am using sqlite database and have a messages table which is storing who is sending what message to who and at what time. Messages table has following columns
Id number/integer
body string
from uuid
to uuid
inserted_at datetime
what i want is to find out how many messages are exchange between two users.
using following query
    SELECT "from", "to", COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY "from", "to";

I get this result which is showing two rows for a single chat session due to my simple table structure.
Notice 117d8b9a-b089-45da-8e1c-879108bdbf1a sent 1 total message to 1646471d-63dc-40fc-b4c5-599f9f1e54d0.
In response 1646471d-63dc-40fc-b4c5-599f9f1e54d0 replied with 3 messages.
So i want a query that shows count 4 between user A and B.
From                                    To.                                    Count
117d8b9a-b089-45da-8e1c-879108bdbf1a    1646471d-63dc-40fc-b4c5-599f9f1e54d0    1
1646471d-63dc-40fc-b4c5-599f9f1e54d0    117d8b9a-b089-45da-8e1c-879108bdbf1a    3
1646471d-63dc-40fc-b4c5-599f9f1e54d0    1d7a6815-91ab-4cc3-a1ba-b07e295945e2    1
1d7a6815-91ab-4cc3-a1ba-b07e295945e2    1646471d-63dc-40fc-b4c5-599f9f1e54d0    8

I tried to give as much information I can let me know if you have any questions to understand problem better.
Thanks.
This works for me and i get that from chatgpt.
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN "from" < "to" THEN "from" 
    ELSE "to" 
  END AS user1,
  CASE 
    WHEN "from" < "to" THEN "to" 
    ELSE "from" 
  END AS user2,
  COUNT(*) AS count
FROM messages
GROUP BY user1, user2;

i will mark the solution that right which was suggesting cases and doing magic like this.

what database are you using ?

Make it easy to assist you, sample data like 1, 2, 3 is much easier to read than 1646471d-63dc-40fc-b4c5-559f9f1e54d0, 1646471d-63dc-40fc-b4c5-599f9fLe54d0, 1646471d-68dc-40fc-b4c5-599f9f1e54d0.

For this you need a recursive cte, so you need to check your database system

you write that 1 message send from A to B, and 3 from B to A, makes 4. I don't see that in your sample data, it would be easier if your sample data also had A, B and so on just like in your explanation

sqllite databas is holding all this data

@GuidoG check first two rows ids are shifting

@NajamAwan This works for me and i get that from chatgpt. I am failing to understand how it works ? You are repeating the same thing twice. See here  the difference between my suggestions and your attempt. Can you add a fiddle ? Have you tried MAX and MIN suggested in my answer ?

Sqlite does not support LEAST and GREATEST but have min(X,Y,...) and  max(X,Y,...)


The multi-argument max() function returns the argument with the maximum value, or return NULL if any argument is NULL

The multi-argument min() function returns the argument with the minimum value




You could use,
SELECT  MIN(from_user, to_user) as  fromUsr,
        MAX(from_user, to_user) as  toUsr,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM  messages
GROUP BY fromUsr , toUsr ;

Or a CASE expression
SELECT  CASE WHEN from_user < to_user THEN from_user ELSE to_user END AS fromUsr,
        CASE WHEN from_user > to_user THEN from_user ELSE to_user END AS toUsr,
        COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM  messages
GROUP BY fromUsr , toUsr;

See example

SELECT
CASE
WHEN "from" < "to" THEN "from"
ELSE "to"
END AS user1,
CASE
WHEN "from" < "to" THEN "to"
ELSE "from"
END AS user2,
COUNT(*) AS count
FROM messages
GROUP BY user1, user2;
this works me using case.

If your DBMS features LEAST/GREATEST scalar functions
SELECT LEAST("from", "to") A, GREATEST ("from", "to") B, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM messages
GROUP BY LEAST("from", "to"), GREATEST ("from", "to")
ORDER BY LEAST("from", "to"), GREATEST ("from", "to");

otherwise emulate them with CASE.

no sqllite doesn't support that. Sorry i didnt't mention about sqlite

You beat me to it, I did already made a dbfiddle for sql server, if you want to use it here it is

then edit your question, and add a tag for sqlite

If your database is supporting analytical functions, you can consolidate into unique pairs before calculating count.
SELECT 
    LEAST("from", "to") AS user1,
    GREATEST("from", "to") AS user2,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM 
    messages
GROUP BY 
    LEAST("from", "to"), 
    GREATEST("from", "to");


no function LEAST so i guess sqlite doesnt support that

then edit your question, and add a tag for sqlite
